# HorizontalScrollBar on a StackPanel

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, stackpanel

I have a StackPanel that gets filled with custom UserControls. I'd like to include a horizontal scroll bar on the bottom of this stack panel that allows users to view the scroll left or right to view more user controls.

What I have now, while it works, seems incorrect in the sense that the size of the ItemsPanel is decided by the ScrollViewer. What I mean by this is if I adjust the vertical scroll bar and shrink it, this also shrinks the stack panel and in order to see it, I need to scroll down. I've tried putting the ScrollViewer inside of the ItemsControl but that doesn't work.

```
<Window x:Name="MainWindow" x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Test Generator" Height="464.5" Width="950">
<Grid>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="New"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Open Template"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Save Template"/>
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Button Content="Load Template" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98"/>
    <Button Content="Add Col" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,36,35,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button x:Name="Generate_Data" Content="Generate Data Window" Height="22" Margin="0,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="Generate_Data_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="0,197,0,0">
            <ItemsControl Name="userControlContainer" Margin="10,150,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the outer `ScrollViewer` you have, and add it to the `ControlTemplate` of the `ItemsControl` itself.

```
<ItemsControl Name="userControlContainer" Margin="10,150,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This works beautifully, exactly as I need. May I ask where you obtained this information, if you looked it up somewhere online?

Comment: I had a similar issue when I first started working with custom ItemsControl, this was the method I came up with. I looked at the default ItemsControl template and saw how the built in Scroll worked. I can't remember where, but I believe I used this as a source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete outer `<ScrollViewer/>` and set the attached property of `<StackPanel ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`/>.

The complete example:

```
<ItemsControl Name="userControlContainer" Margin="10,150,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried Visible instead of Auto as well.

Comment: @TalenKylon could you write more cleat what you want. Do you want to resize just items placed in `<StackPanel/>`?

Comment: I don't want to resize them necessarily, I want a horizontal scroll bar that will allow me to look at more of them in the event that the number of items in StackPanel exceeds the view of the application. Then we scroll to the left or the right to see more.